# One object gets stuck with two while loops

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm trying to add physics to the paddle object whenever I press "w", but the ball object gets stuck until the `while` loop is finished in the `paddle_up()` function. How do I make the ball keep moving while the paddle is jumping?

The point of this game is avoiding the ball coming from the right. Whenever the user avoids the ball he or she gets one point, but whenever it collide's with the paddle, they lose one point:

```
import random
import turtle


# window setup

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Jump Game")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width=1000, height=750)
wn.tracer(0)

# Key Biding Functions


def paddle_up():
    paddle_a.dy = -0.1
    while paddle_a.ycor() < 0:
        paddle_a.sety(paddle_a.ycor() - paddle_a.dy)
        wn.update()


def paddle_down():
    y = paddle_a.ycor()
    y -= 10
    paddle_a.sety(y)


def paddle_left():
    x = paddle_a.xcor()
    x -= 10
    paddle_a.setx(x)


def paddle_right():
    x = paddle_a.xcor()
    x += 10
    paddle_a.setx(x)

# Paddle A


paddle_a = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_a.speed(1)
paddle_a.shape("square")
paddle_a.color("white")
paddle_a.shapesize(stretch_wid=2, stretch_len=2, outline=1)
paddle_a.penup()
paddle_a.goto(-480, -350)

# Ball

ball = turtle.Turtle()
ball.shape("circle")
ball.color("white")
ball.penup()
ball.goto(-350, 0)
ball_speed = random.random()
ball_position_y = random.randint(-350, -300)

# Score System
Score = 0
Scr = turtle.Turtle()
Scr.goto(0, 360)
Scr.color("white")
Scr.penup()
Scr.hideturtle()

wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(paddle_up, "w")
wn.onkeypress(paddle_down, "s")
wn.onkeypress(paddle_left, "a")
wn.onkeypress(paddle_right, "d")

# Main Game Loop


while True:
    wn.update()
    ball.setx(ball.xcor() - ball_speed * 0.3)
    if ball_speed <= 0.3:
        ball_speed = 0.3
    if ball.xcor() < paddle_a.xcor() + 20 and ball.xcor() > paddle_a.xcor() - 20 and ball.ycor() < paddle_a.ycor() +20 and ball.ycor() > paddle_a.ycor() - 20:
        Score = Score - 1
        Scr.clear()
        Scr.write("Score{}".format(Score), align="center", font=("Courier", 24))
        ball.setx(490)
        ball_position_y = random.randint(-350, -300)
        ball.sety(ball_position_y)
    elif ball.xcor() <= -490 and ball.ycor() != paddle_a.ycor():
        Score = Score + 1
        Scr.clear()
        Scr.write("Score{}".format(Score), align="center", font=("Courier", 24))
        ball.setx(490)
        ball_position_y = random.randint(-350, -300)
        ball.sety(ball_position_y)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `while` loops where you should be using timer events.  SO is full of Python turtle game answers that say, "`while True:` has no business in an event-driven world like turtle."  How could you miss them?

I've reworked your code below to make it basically playable:

```
from random import randint
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

FONT = ('Courier', 24)

# Key Biding Functions

def paddle_up():
    def paddle_rise():
        if paddle.ycor() < 0:
            paddle.sety(paddle.ycor() + paddle.dy)
            screen.update()
            screen.ontimer(paddle_rise, 10)

    paddle_rise()

def paddle_down():
    paddle.sety(paddle.ycor() - 10)

def paddle_left():
    paddle.setx(paddle.xcor() - 10)

def paddle_right():
    paddle.setx(paddle.xcor() + 10)

def update_score():
    global ball_speed

    scorer.clear()
    scorer.write("Score: {}".format(score), align='center', font=FONT)
    ball.setposition(490, randint(-350, -300))
    ball_speed = randint(1, 3)

# Main Game Loop

def play():
    global score

    ball.setx(ball.xcor() - ball_speed)

    if ball.distance(paddle) <= 20:
        score -= 1
        update_score()
    elif ball.xcor() <= -490 and ball.ycor() != paddle.ycor():
        score += 1
        update_score()

    screen.update()

    screen.ontimer(play, 10)

# window setup

screen = Screen()
screen.title("Jump Game")
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.setup(width=1000, height=800)
screen.tracer(0)

# Paddle A

paddle = Turtle()
paddle.shape('square')
paddle.color('white')
paddle.shapesize(stretch_wid=2, stretch_len=2, outline=1)
paddle.speed('slowest')
paddle.penup()
paddle.goto(-480, -350)

paddle.dy = 2

# Ball

ball = Turtle()
ball.shape('circle')
ball.color('white')
ball.penup()
ball.setposition(490, randint(-350, -300))

ball_speed = randint(1, 3)

# Score System
score = 0

scorer = Turtle()
scorer.hideturtle()
scorer.sety(360)
scorer.color('white')
scorer.penup()

scorer.write("Score: {}".format(score), align='center', font=FONT)

screen.onkeypress(paddle_up, 'w')
screen.onkeypress(paddle_down, 's')
screen.onkeypress(paddle_left, 'a')
screen.onkeypress(paddle_right, 'd')
screen.listen()

play()

screen.mainloop()
```